# Map.containsValue returns False although specified value exists in valueset and there is no objecttype mismatch

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, int, long-integer

I've tried to check valuesset Hashmap  using contains method passing an integer -1. Although this value is present in valueset it returns null. My Map is  (String,Integer) format however looking through debug I can see -1 in Map is stored as Long (I did tried to check contains by Long.valueof(-1) which is also false).

[image: code and debug screen shot]

Comment: How do you know that `dataSnapshot2` actually contains any data?  Your screen shot does not show this inspection.  Can you edit your question and include code?

Comment: check line 3 on debugger in screenshot.. there are values on dataSnapshot2

Comment: Why is there a `Long` value in a `Map<String, Integer>`?

Comment: Try using  `-1L`

Comment: @cricket_007 it's still false

Comment: Why aren't you using `dataSnapshot2.getValue(User.class)`? Or something similar?

Comment: `frndrqst_listener'`listener is attached to User object's `relationship` Map on Firebase so only datachanges at `relationship ` for user object will trigger this method and therefore `dataSnapshot2` will only pass relationship values not the whole object

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your scenario I tried the following, but its working for me:

```
public static void mapContainsIssue() {

        // create hash map
        HashMap<String, Integer> newmap = new HashMap<>();

        // populate hash map
        newmap.put("tutorials", 23);
        newmap.put("point", -1);
        newmap.put("is best", 2);

        // check existence of value 'point'
        System.out.println("Check if value '-1' exists: "
                + newmap.containsValue(-1));
    }
```

Comment: well for my problem only this fix is returning true `if(req_wat_user.relationship.values().toString().contains("-1"))`